# Explanation regarding alternating sum estimations

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can somebody please explain why $|s_{n+1}-s_n |\geq |s-s_n|$?

> **Error estimate for alternating series**
>
> If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies the conditions of the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) so that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges to the sum $s$, then the error in the approximation $s\approx s_n$ (where $n\ge N$) has the same sign as the first omitted term $a_{n+1} = s_{n+1} - s_n$, and its size is no greater than the size of that term: $$|s-s_n| \le |s_{n+1}-s_n| = |a_{n+1}|$$

**My confusion**

$s=\sum_1^\infty a_n $, $s_{n+1} = \sum^{n+1}_1 a_n$. So isnt by definition $s>s_{n+1}$ and hence $|s_{n+1}-s_n |\leq |s-s_n|$?

Comment: That's the content of the statement. It's just saying the size of the error in the approximation (that's $|s-s_n|$) is no greater than (that's "$\leq$") the size of the first omitted term (that's $|s_{n+1}-s_n|$). Are you asking someone to prove the statement you posted? Doesn't the text do that? You do see that $s_{n+1}-s_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are the same thing, right?

Comment: I am aware of that. What I am asking is to prove $|s-s_n|\leq |s_{n+1}-s_n|$

Comment: For the "My Confusion" edit, two remarks: 1. Why has $a_n$ suddenly become $f(x)$ ? 2. Since half of the $a_n$ terms are negative, you cannot generally say that $s>s_{n+1}$, this depends on the parity of $n$.

Comment: 1. Edited. 2. Yes that was what basically bugging me. How do I resolve that?

Comment: Please note that your indices in $s_{n+1}$ are incorrect...

Comment: Oh yes apologies for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that $|a_n|$ is decreasing, can you show that $s\in [s_n;s_{n+1}]$ when $a_{n+1}>0$ and $s\in [s_{n+1};s_n]$ when $a_{n+1}<0$ ?

*edit:*

That means, can you show that $a_{n+1}>0\Rightarrow s_n<s<s_{n+1}$ and that $a_{n+1}<0\Rightarrow s_{n+1}<s<s_n$ ?

*second edit:*

The trick in that kind of proof is to consider the two monotonous series $s_{2n}$ and $s_{2n+1}$. One is increasing (*wlog*, let's say the first one) and the other one is decreasing, but both have the same limit $s$. So you can conclude that $\forall n,s>s_{2n}$ and $s<s_{2n+1}$.

*third edit:*

Assume $a_1>0$.

Because $a_n$ is an alternating series, $a_{2n+1}>0$ and $a_{2n}<0,\forall n$.

Because $a_n$ match the convergence criteria, $|a_n|$ is decreasing to zero. Notice that the subseries $|a_{2n}|$ and $|a_{2n+1}|$ are also decreasing and convergent to $0$.

For any $n$, $s_{2(n+1)}-s_{2n}=a_{2n+1}+a_{2n+2}=|a_{2n+1}|-|a_{2n+2}|>0$ because $a_{2n+1}>0$ and $a_{2n+2}<0$, and because $|a_n|$ is decreasing.
We conclude that $s_{2n}$ is increasing. As a subseries of $s_n$, it converges to $s$, so $\forall n, s_{2n}<s$.

The same reasonning with the series $s_{2n+1}$ proves that $\forall n, s<s_{2n+1}$.

From $\forall n, s_{2n}<s<s_{2n+1}$, we conclude that $|s_{2n+1}-s|<|s_{2n+1}-s_{2n}|$.
From $\forall n, s_{2n-1}>s>s_{2n}$, we conclude that $|s_{2n}-s|<|s_{2n}-s_{2n-1}|$.

Since this covers both possible parity of the indice, we have $\forall n,|s_{n+1}−s_n|≥|s−s_n|$

Comment: I am not fluent with set terminologies. Can you please rewrite it more simply?

Comment: Apologies but I can't figure out how to show that. It's easy to notice the relation between $s_{n+1}$ and $s_n$ but I can't work out the reasoning behind the proposed relations of $s_{n+1}$ and $s$

Comment: Please check my second edit, I hope it helps...

Comment: I am very very sorry but I couldn't understand that.

Comment: Can you understand why $s_{2n}$ is monotonous ?

Comment: Yes because by assumption the modulus of each term is decreasing and so even though the sign changes between terms the resulting effect is lower than the preceding number. The same is for $s_{2n+1}$.

Comment: OHHH. I think I got it. Please check it if it sounds correct. Lets say there is a series $a_1,-a_2,a_3,-a_4,a_5,-a_6,a_7,-a_8....$. Let's say $n=7$. So $a_{n+1}=-a_8<0$. . Now this is easy to notice that $s_n>s_{n+1}$ and $s_n>s$ since $s$ and $s_{n+1}$ contain an additional negative term. And now since in $s$ the remainder of terms will maintain positivity due to ${a_9}$ being positive thus $s>s_{n+1}$. Now I am waiting for a rigorous proof. If you can provide it or come across it let me know.

Comment: I think you got the right intuition, but may I ask what's your background in real analysis ? Your use of notations is a bit surprising and it is rare for someone who is not used to standard notations to venture into demonstrations about sums of series...

Comment: I am a pre-university student so I have never studied real analysis (it wasn't taught mathematics as rigorously in high school). But I have spent a lot of amount self-studying so your statement seems a little frightening for me. (I now realize I made an error while writing series but actually showed a sequence)